# Image in splash screen is repeated

Tags: android

I'm intending to show a very simple splash screen using a theme and an @drawable xml for the background.

Styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splashx</item>
</style>
```

Splashx.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

For some reason, the top few pixels are repeated when the splash screen is displayed, like so:
[image]

The actual image that I used obviously doesn't have this distortion on top (the little triangle on top which is essentially the hand and the club repeated from below). I've tried it with a few other images, too. Same mysteria.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try shifting your image from drawable to the mipmap folder? and then adding the mipmap image as a bitmap to your layer list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@color/your_background_color"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/your_image"/>
</item>
```

See the link here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/